# PHP - Create API with authenticated requests

Tags: php

I've created a simple PHP restful API like:

Register

```
api?action=register&username=xcodeWarrier&email=test@gmail.com&password=abc
```

To post content

```
api?action=postContent&content=123&username=xcodeWarrier
```

How do I protect the postContent API call to prevent anyone posting content as xcodeWarrier.

Comment: You need a way to identify, that sender of the request is really xcodeWarrier. You can send his password inside the request. But remember, you'll need https to protect the data.

Comment: Ok so what if xcodeWarrier used Twitter oauth to authenticate and I don't have his password, rather just an oauth token and secret thats just been provided by Twitter...

Comment: You must get enough information to authenticate the user: his unique ID, and the secret password. In case of twitter it's his token and secret.